# Debugging nestjs micro-service framework

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, microservices, nestjs

How can we debug the nest micro-service framework in vscode,

The framework is a typescript project with springboot conventions

[http://nestjs.com](https://nestjs.com/)

Answer (score 3):

press F5, choose Node, replace launch.json file to:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
            "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts"],
            "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register"],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
    ]
}
```

So put a breackpoint and hit F5 again.

Comment: When debugging "Step Over" not working properly (opens system .js files)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using nestjs 6.8+ (see [here](https://trilon.io/blog/announcing-nestjs-monorepos-and-new-commands#Migration-strategy))

add `launch.json` in `.vscode` folder with this content

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach NestJS WS",
      "port": 9229,
      "restart": true,
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "skipFiles": [
         "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
         "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*.js",
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

then run `npn run start:debug`

then in vscode choose `Attach NestJs Ws`

Done! you can set break point
[image]

Comment: I just run "npn run start:debug" and my vs code automatically starts debug session. (i enabled Debugger Attach with flag in VS Code settings).